# Open item from a different External List (BDC connector)

Tags: 2013, list, external-list, list-item

I have a "Quote List" and "Task List".

Both are external lists, using BDCM custom connector (from WCF services)

I'm using Sharepoint 2013.

A new task will be create when a quote is approved. So on the "Task List" user will want to look at the original quote, that means, I'm putting a column say "View Quote", which opens that quote item in a modal dialog box (there will be logics to find the quoteID from the taskID).

Is there any ways to open an item from a different external list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kris,

You can actually use calculated column to prepare a dynamic Hyperlink in your list view, please have a look at:
[Using calculated columns to write HTML](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/)

You can use the same script to prepare an anchor tag which calls a method in JavaScript.. And you can place a Content Editor Web Part on your page, where you can define that method to open a Modal Dialog..

You can download the latest script here:
[HTML Calculated Column](http://pathtosharepoint.com/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx)

One of the implementations where I need to show custom checkbox selectors for the item:
[SharePoint 2010: Get Selected Items from List View in Visual Web Part](http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/sharepoint-2010-get-selected-items-from-list-view-in-visual-web-part/)

Let me know if you need any help

Comment: Hi Arsalan, Just want to ask when generating the link, how can I find the ID for the list item? do you know how SP generates them..? e.g.: DispForm.aspx?ID=__ck8100530003000300030013008300g40000300

Comment: Here is the trick, when you use Calculated Columns.. The Id is not yet prepared when the value is calculated, to overcome this I added a separate field and once the Item is added.. I updated this field with the ID of the Item.. Use this custom Id field in calculated columns and it should work!

Comment: Because mine is an external list, from WCF. So would the ID change everytime..? how does it work internally? thanks again!!